# Find if there exists any path between two specified vertices in a weighted digraph

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am trying to implement a method `isReachable(E fromKey, E toKey)` to determine if any path exists between the two specified vertices in the graph. I have a generic class `Graph<E>` that uses two inner data structures, `Vertex` and `Edge`, to represent the vertices and edges of the graph. Here is the code for that:

```
public class Graph<E extends Comparable<E>> implements GraphAPI<E>
{
    /*
     * number of vertices (size of this graph)
     */
    private long order;
    /**
     * pointer to the list of vertices
     */
    private Vertex first;

    /**
     * A vertex of a graph stores a data item and references
     * to its edge list and the succeeding vertex. The data
     * object extends the comparable interface.
     */
    private class Vertex
    {
        /**
         * pointer to the next vertex
         */
        public Vertex pNextVertex;
        /**
         * the data item
         */
        public E data;
        /**
         * indegree
         */
        public long inDeg;
        /**
         * outdegree
         */
        public long outDeg;
        /**
         * pointer to the edge list
         */
        public Edge pEdge;
        /**
         * Field for tracking vertex accesses
         */
        public long processed;
    }

    /**
     * An edge of a graph contains a reference to the destination
     * vertex, a reference to the succeeding edge in the edge list and
     * the weight of the directed edge.
     */
    private class Edge
    {
        /**
         * pointer to the destination vertex
         */
        public Vertex destination;
        /**
         * weight on this edge
         */
        public Double weight;
        /**
         * pointer to the next edge
         */
        public Edge pNextEdge;
    }
    /**
     * Constructs an empty weighted directed graph
     */
    public Graph()
    {
        first = null;
        order = 0;
    }
}
```

This is my thought process:
(1) Walk through the list of vertices until reaching the Vertex containing the specified `fromKey`; (2) add each adjacent Vertex to the `fromKey` to a queue; (3) while the queue is not empty, retrieve and remove the Vertex at the head of the queue and compare it's key to the `toKey`; and (4) if it's a match return true, otherwise keep searching through the edge list of each adjacent Vertex.

Here is my code for the method so far:

```
/**
 * Determines whether there is an outdirected path between two
 * vertices.
 * @param fromKey - search key of the originating vertex.
 * @param toKey - search key of the destination vertex.
 * @return true on success or false on failure.
 */
public boolean isReachable(E fromKey, E toKey)
{
    ArrayList<Vertex> queue = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    E tmpKey = fromKey;
    Edge tmpEdge;
    Vertex tmp = first;
    while (tmp != null)
    {
        if (tmp.data.equals(tmpKey))
        {
            tmpEdge = tmp.pEdge;
            while (tmpEdge != null)
            {
                queue.add(tmpEdge.destination);
                tmpEdge = tmpEdge.pNextEdge;
            }
            tmp = first;
            tmpKey = queue.remove(0).data;
            if (tmpKey.equals(toKey))
                return true;
        }
        tmp = tmp.pNextVertex;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works when a path between the two specified keys exists, but throws an index out of bounds error when there does not.

This is an adjacency list I traced for the sample data I have:

```
1  -> null
2  -> 1 -> 11 -> 12 -> null
3  -> 2 -> 4 -> null
4  -> null
5  -> 4 -> null
6  -> 5 -> 7 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> null
7  -> 12 -> null
8  -> 7 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> null
9  -> 1 -> null
10 -> null
11 -> 1 -> 12 -> null
12 -> null
13 -> null
14 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
15 -> 3 -> 5 -> 14 -> null
```

When i call `isReachable(5, 3)`, for instance, I get an index out of bounds exception. But if i call the method on (15, 2), it returns true.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. A friend suggested trying a BFS approach to the problem, but I didn't really follow his explanation. Am I on the right track? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *but throws an index out of bounds error* - where does it do this? how about showing the log. What have you done to try to debug this?

Comment: Not an answer but don't use an arraylist like a queue, use a queue :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic graph search algorithm, google "breadth first search" as a starting point. You need to keep track of nodes you've visited, which I don't see you having done yet.

Also, as I said in my comment, don't use an `ArrayList` to maintain a queue, the `remove` operation is slow, particularly removing the elements at the start of the array as you have to copy everything across by 1. Use a `Queue` directly (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)